# Pandas row operation with values from different dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
df
col1    col2
 1       2
 3       4
 5       6
```

And a dictionary like this,

```
 dictionary={1:5, 3:10, 5:15}
```

Now I am writing a function which will take col1, col2 and the dict values as input and return some output,

```
def  x(col1, col2, dictionary):
     return col1*col2*dictionary.get(col1)
```

The expected output is

```
col1    col2    col3
 1       2       10
 3       4       120
 5       6       450
```

Now I can use a for loop and to get the value for each row, but this is taking longer time to execute, looking for pandas sortcuts to do this more efficiently

Comment: kindly add your expected output

Comment: expected output is added

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df.col1*df.col2*df.col1.map(dictionary)
```

If you want a function, you can edit it, and use pandas' `pipe` method:

```
def  x(df, col1, col2, dictionary):
     return df.assign(col3 = df[col1]*df[col2]*df[col1].map(dictionary))

df.pipe(x, 'col1', 'col2', dictionary)
 
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     2    10
1     3     4   120
2     5     6   450
```

Comment: I want to use the function x, I kept the function simple here which can be very complex

Comment: @Kallol - hmmm, if very complex function not easy say if possible, if not posted all complex function.

Comment: @Kallol - Obviously for custom function is bottleneck you need use it (because not exist vectorize alternative)